# How To Prevent Drop Down Menu From Closing When User Clicks Into It?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, drop-down-menu

I followed a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) on W3Schools website about making a dropdown menu from a button.  Everything works fine EXCEPT that when the user clicks inside the dropdown menu the menu itself disappears.

I wanted to make a LOGIN button where the user clicks on the button, it displays a dropdown menu where he/she can input his/her username and password and click Login.

I want to keep the feature where if the user clicks any other area **outside** the drop down menu, it would automatically close the drop down menu.

My problem is that the dropdown menu disappears when the user clicks any area **inside** it.  How do I prevent it from disappearing while clicking inside the drop down menu using only **JavaScript**?  What about using **jQuery** (I'm not really familiar with jQuery yet)

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Contents inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content input, .dropdown-content button {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">LOG IN</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"/>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you going to have only one dropdown on the page?

Comment: I already have other drop downs in the <nav> element with different class names and id.  They're all working fine so far.

Comment: so they should be closed when clicked inside?

Comment: For the other dropdowns, I'm fine with them closing when clicked inside since they're only links.  For this one, it's different because it's a Log In feature and users have to click inside and the dropdown actually has to stay open while users type their info

Comment: This is the only one on this page with this feature.

Comment: [check this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On window.onClick handler, we add a condition to exclude "dropdown content" and its children.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    // [BEGIN][Here is the condition]
    if (event.target.matches('.dropdown-content') || event.target.matches('.dropdown-content *') ) {
       event.stopPropagation();
       return;
    }
  // [END][Here is the condition]
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Contents inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content input, .dropdown-content button {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">LOG IN</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"/>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click inside dropdown,
you should not remove show class

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
   
  if (event.target.matches('.dropdown-content *')) {
    return;
   } 

  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Contents inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content input, .dropdown-content button {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">LOG IN</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" class="form-input" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```